# Using a different codec with Csv parser in Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to read a csv from google cloud storage in Google Cloud Datalab but its falling over with the following error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ba47ebe88c7a> in <module>()
    17 fn = generate_input_fn(filename)
    18 k,v = fn()
---> 19 csv.browse(max_lines = 1000)
    20 
    21 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/datalab/data/_csv.pyc in browse(self, max_lines, headers)
    89     """
    90     if self.path.startswith('gs://'):
---> 91       lines = Csv._read_gcs_lines(self.path, max_lines)
    92     else:
    93       lines = Csv._read_local_lines(self.path, max_lines)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/datalab/data/_csv.pyc in _read_gcs_lines(path, max_lines)
    56   @staticmethod
    57   def _read_gcs_lines(path, max_lines=None):
---> 58     return datalab.storage.Item.from_url(path).read_lines(max_lines)
    59 
    60   @staticmethod

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/datalab/storage/_item.pyc in read_lines(self, max_lines)
    200       content = self.read_from(byte_count=bytes_to_read)
    201 
--> 202       lines = content.split('\n')
    203       if len(lines) > max_lines or bytes_to_read >= max_to_read:
    204         break

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 35587: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems that this is because the file is not encoded in ascii but that the csv parser assumes ascii.

**Is there a way I can have the [csv parser](http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/google.datalab.data.html) datalab provides use a different codec other than ascii?**

I had a look at the docs but couldn't see a way to pass a codec as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datalab csv parser uses the python csv module under the hood, and that module itself doesn't support encodings/codecs.

If the file isn't too big you can use the [gcs view](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/tutorials/Storage/Storage%20Commands.ipynb) command to load it into a variable, then encode it and pass it to a csv reader.

That command just reads the whole file, so if you need to limit the number of lines you'd have to use the [read_lines() method in the Storage API](http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/google.datalab.storage.html#google.datalab.storage.Object.read_lines).